# How to get current plot's clim in matplotlib

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

After plotting in Matlab we do `caxis(max(caxis()) - [0.5, 0])` to scale the color limits to go from the current max color limit to, say, 0.5 below this max. This works because `caxis()` in Matlab both gets and sets the color limits. How does one do this in matplotlib?

That is, I want to achieve the following:

```
import numpy.random, numpy, pylab
arr = numpy.random.randn(100,100)
pylab.figure()
pylab.imshow(arr)
pylab.colorbar()
pylab.clim([numpy.max(arr.ravel())-0.5, numpy.max(arr.ravel())]) # [*]
pylab.show()
```

*without* the asterisked call to `pylab.clim()` having recourse to `arr`, the array being plotted. In other words, how can I get the current figure's "clim" in matplotlib?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you didn't keep the returned image object, you can use `pylab.gci` to get the current ScalarMappable (i.e. whatever the current colorbar would be based on).

From there, you just want the `get_clim` method of the ScalarMappable object.

So, you could do:

```
vmin, vmax = plt.gci().get_clim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a 2006 mailing list conversation showing me the way:

```
im = pylab.imshow(arr)
pylab.clim(im.norm.vmax - numpy.array([0.5, 0]))
```